# How do I contact Rockstar customer support?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Recently, Rockstar Social Club has been hacked and thousands of people's login data has been stolen. I'm pretty sure I'm a victim, as I have progressed only about 1-3 levels in online. Now I'm almost level 10, lost my 1,000,000 pre-order bonus dollars, have a completely new outfit (at least the cat shirt is nice) and own a garage on an abandoned beach. I have travelled about only 5 miles in-game, so I have never been there.

This is really bugging me. I looked on their website, but I only can find the knowledge base, FAQ and so on - no customer support.

I would like to send them an email with my issue, or maybe a live online chat.

**Where and how can I contact Rockstar's customer support?**

Comment: This should go without saying, but change all your passwords ;)

Comment: Already done, but thanks for the reminder. :) Email will be changed when the support question is done, as it is linked to the mail.

Comment: What? I observed a suspicious thing as well but let it slide. My shirt got a subtle "tree of life" emblem on it and I got -2 levels (142 from 144). I just inferred that they mistakenly rolled back due to some error since Rockstar serves are never smooth on weekends. Does anyone think my account has been compromised as well?

Comment: @Ejay That depends - has anything else changed, and have other users experienced similar things?

Comment: Check your money and so on. Still change your password, as they may have retrieved it but not used yet.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can submit a request [here](https://support.rockstargames.com/categories/200013306).

[image: screenshot of page]

Answer (score 0):

Just like [Paul Crozier](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/99060/paul-crozier) said, you can send a request aka a ticket. Yet I can't get any answers from there.

However, I found and called Rockstar's phone support and they helped me with my problems.

The number I called was 1-866-405-5464. However they take a long time to answer, especially after banwaves (there was one 3 days ago for example). Also they don't work 7/24. You must call them accordingly to the US time.

And for calling: You can call them for free with [Google Voice](https://www.google.com/voice). To do so, add the number in a contact in your Gmail Contacts and just click the number. Google Voice popup will ask you the confirm the number and then you will call them.

Have fun!